# Calendar View with Day, week, month views in iOS with events

Tags: ios, xcode, calendar

Please help me to create the events for iOS calendar with Day, week and months views as shown below.

In the first view i need to display the calendar and by selecting the particular day in the calendar i need to navigate to the same day in the other view which is a Day or Week View with time 12 am to 12 pm on the view. and also we need to add the events.